# Rails/ActiveRecord Group by month+year with counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table of `Albums` that has a `date` column named `release_date`.

I want to get a list of all the month + year combinations present along with the number of albums released in that month/year.

So, the output might be something like:

- November 2016 - 11
- October 2016 - 4
- July 2016 - 19
- December 2015 - 2

Ruby 2.3.1 w/ Rails 5 on Postgres 9.6, FWIW.

Comment: It is quite simple using SQL: `select to_char(release_date, 'Month YYYY'), count(*) from albums group by 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your table is singular `Album` per Rails convention. If not, consider changing it.

```
 Album.all.map { |album| [Date::MONTHNAMES[album.date.month], album.date.year].join(' ') }
  .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |month_year, counts| counts[month_year] += 1 }
```

Explanation:

The `.map` method iterates over the albums and returns an array of strings consisting of `["month year", "month year", ... ]`.

The `.each_with_object` method is a standard counting algorithm that returns a hash with a count for each unique array item.

Answer (score 9):

Database layer is where this task belongs, not Ruby:

```
Album.group("TO_CHAR(release_date, 'Month YYYY')").count
```

Why using database layer? Simply because it is lightning fast compared to nearly anything else, it is resource-efficient **especially** compared to Ruby, it scales perfectly and because having tons of `Album` records you can simply overload memory and never actually finish the processing.