# Group by decade with counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a table of `Album`'s that has a `date` column named `release_date`.

I want to get a list of all the decades along with the number of albums released in that decade.

So, the output might be something like:

- 2010 - 11
- 2000 - 4
- 1990 - 19
- 1940 - 2

Ruby 2.3.1 w/ Rails 5 on Postgres 9.6, FWIW.

This is essentially a followup question to a previous one I had: [Group by month+year with counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538996/get-list-of-month-year-combinations-present-along-with-count)

Which may help with the solution...I'm just not sure how to do the grouping by decade.

Comment: I am wondering whether you checked the solution I've provided to this question and also [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538996/group-by-monthyear-with-counts/40583253#40583253)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Ruby for processing db data is inefficient in all senses.

I would suggest doing it on the database level:

```
Album.group("(DATE_PART('year', release_date)::int / 10) * 10").count
```

What happens here, is basically you take a year part of the `release_date`, cast it to integer, take it's decade and count albums for this group.

Say, we have a `release_date` of `"2016-11-13T08:30:03+02:00"`:

```
2016 / 10 * 10
#=> 2010
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is pretty similar to your earlier question. In this case, instead of creating month/year combinations and using the combinations as your grouping criteria, you need a method that returns the decade base year from the album year.

Since you have a pattern developing, think about writing the code so it can be reused.

```
def album_decades
  Album.all.map { |album| album.release_date.year / 10 * 10 }
end

def count_each(array)
  array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |element, counts| counts[element] += 1 }
end
```

Now you can call `count_each(album_decades)` for the result you want. See if you can write a method `album_months_and_years` that will produce the result you want from your earlier question by calling `count_each(album_months_and_years)`.

Answer (score -1):

There are more than one possible solution to your problem, but I would try:

1. Add a new column to the `Album` table, called `decade`. You can use a migration for this porpoise.
2. Create a callback (its like a trigger, but in the programmer side) that set the `decade` value before saving the `Album` in the DB.
3. Finally you can use this [useful query](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#total-of-grouped-items) to group the `Album`s by decade. In your case would be `Album.group(:decade).count` wich would give you a hash with the numbers of `Album`s by decade.
4. ...
5. Profit ?

Jokes aside, the callback should be something like:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    # some code ...

    before_save  :set_decade    # this is the 'callback'

    # ...

    private
        def set_decade
            self.decade = self.release_date.year / 10
        end
```

Then, if you use the step 3, it would return something like:

```
# => { '195' => 7, '200' => 12 }
```

I did not test the answer, so try it out and tell me how it went.

Comment: I would avoid persisting redundant data in the database.

Comment: In the practice, you don't really care for redundant data if you know what you are doing. Sometime you avoid "the rules" to make a clearer solution and/or to save time that would take a regular SQL query. I can tell you from the experience of an expert (an old system designer/analist: my teacher).